# Why take the address of an array element like `&myArray[i]`? Bidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

There's some code where it creates a float array like this:

```
mData = new float[channelCount * maxFrames];
```

then it does

```
memcpy(&mData[sampleIndex],
                   buffer,
                   (numSamples * sizeof(float)));
```

What does `&mData[sampleIndex]` mean? Well, we have a float array, we take an element of that array, and then take the address of that element. Wouldn't the address of that element be `mData + sampleIndex`?

What if I wanted to change `memcpy` by a for loop? I did this and it worked:

```
            for (int i=0; i< numSamples * sizeof(float); i++) {
                (&mData[sampleIndex])[i] = buffer[i];
            }
```

but I don't know what `(&mData[sampleIndex])[i]` means. Should it be `mData + sampleIndex + i`?

This code is supposed to work to record microfone wav data, so we should be able to store things in multiple channels. How this code manages such channels?

Comment: Your loop is wrong, it should be `for (int i=0; i< numSamples; i++)` since you are assigning whole `float`s and not individual bytes, assuming `buffer[]` is an array of `float` to match that `mData` is an array of `float`.

Comment: `memcpy(&mData[sampleIndex], buffer, (numSamples * sizeof(float)));` is useful when you want to `memcpy` data into the middle of an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does &mData[sampleIndex] mean? Well, we have a float array, we take an element of that array, and then take the address of that element. Wouldn't the address of that element be mData + sampleIndex?

Yes.

> What if I wanted to change memcpy by a for loop?

Your loop doesn't quite do the same thing. `memcpy` is copying `numSamples * sizeof(float)` bytes while your loop is copying `numSamples * sizeof(float)` floats. Since a float consists of multiple bytes (on most systems), this may result in a buffer overflow.

> but I don't know what (&mData[sampleIndex])[i] means. Should it be mData + sampleIndex + i?

It's not quite the same. `(&mData[sampleIndex])[i]` would be equal to `*(mData + sampleIndex + i)`

> How this code manages such channels?

This code simply copies values from one array into another. It doesn't "manage" anything.

Comment: How can I copy `numSamples * sizeof(float)` bytes instead of floats?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs by copying `numSamples` floats.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `array[index]` is the same as `*(array + index)`, thus:

`&mData[sampleIndex]`

is the same as:

`&(*(mData + sampleIndex))`

Which is simply:

`mData + sampleIndex`

And so, `(&mData[sampleIndex])[i]` is getting a `float*` pointer to the `mData` element at index `sampleIndex`, and then applying the index `i` to that pointer.  So yes, in this case:

`(&mData[sampleIndex])[i] = buffer[i];`

is the same as:

`*(mData + sampleIndex + i) = *(buffer + i);`