# How to replace this memcpy by a for loop?

Tags: c++

I asked [Why take the address of an array element like `&myArray[i]`? Bidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63893296/why-take-the-address-of-an-array-element-like-myarrayi-bidimensional-array) and answers pointed out that I'm not doing the same thing in my loop:

```
memcpy(&mData[sampleIndex],
                   buffer,
                   (numSamples * sizeof(float)));
```

I did this `for` loop to replace it:

```
            for (int i=0; i< numSamples * sizeof(float); i++) {
                (&mData[sampleIndex])[i] = buffer[i];
            }
```

but they said I was copying `numSamples * sizeof(float)` floats while the first code copies `numSamples * sizeof(float)` bytes. How can I do the same in the loop?

Comment: `i < numSamples`?

Comment: What are the types of the variables used?

Comment: `memcpy` only operates on bytes, so you need to tell it how many bytes you're copying. Assigning one float to another assigns the whole float in one go. I assume `buffer` and `mData[sampleIndex]` are both of type `float[]`.

Comment: It's very likely `(&mData[sampleIndex])[i]` is the same as just `mData[sampleIndex+i]`.

Comment: The answer will vary, depending on the type of `buffer`, and possibly the type of `mData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`memcpy` copies bytes, so you need to multiply `numSamples` by `sizeof(float)`.  In the `for` loop variant, since every element of the array is a `float` to begin with, and the assignment operator (`=`) assigns a `float` on each iteration, you don't need to multiply by `sizeof(float)`, and just use `numSamples`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++) {
    // Here --------^
    (&mData[sampleIndex])[i] = buffer[i];
}
```